# É possível trabalhar com Enumeradores em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, enums

Comumente usados em diversas linguagens os Enumeradores facilitam a vida dos desenvolvedores quando se necessita criar uma "lista" de valores contantes dentro de uma aplicação. Dentro do `Javascript` é possível usar essa estrutura ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O Javascript não possui enumeradores nativamente mas é algo que consegue implementar com relativa facilidade.

Exemplo:

```js
const corSemaforo = {
  VERDE: 0,
  AMARELO: 1,
  VERMELHO: 2
};

let cor = corSemaforo.VERDE;

if (cor == corSemaforo.VERDE) {
  console.log("O semaforo está verde");
}
```

Até pode melhorar esta ideia e atribuir `strings` com valores mais expressivos em vez de números.

```
const corSemaforo = {
  VERDE: "Verde",
  AMARELO: "Amarelo",
  VERMELHO: "Vermelho"
};
```

Assim se escrever o valor de um `semaforo` algures terá a representação do mesmo em texto:

```
console.log(corSemaforo.VERDE); //Verde
```

### Imutabilidade

Apesar de ter sido declarado como `const` apenas a referência ao objeto é constante o seu conteúdo pode ser modificado. Isto faz com que o programador possa inadvertidamente alterar o enumerado acrescentando, removendo ou alterando propriedades.

Veja o problema:

```js
const corSemaforo = {
  VERDE: "Verde",
  AMARELO: "Amarelo",
  VERMELHO: "Vermelho"
};

corSemaforo.AZUL = "Azul"; //agora já tem mais uma cor
delete corSemaforo["VERDE"]; //removeu o verde

console.log(corSemaforo); //agora sem VERDE e com AZUL
```

Para evitar este problema podemos utilizar a função [`freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) de `Object` que impede o objeto de ser alterado:

```js
const corSemaforo = {
  VERDE: "Verde",
  AMARELO: "Amarelo",
  VERMELHO: "Vermelho"
};

Object.freeze(corSemaforo); //impede futuras alterações

corSemaforo.AZUL = "Azul"; //já não adiciona
delete corSemaforo["VERDE"]; //já não remove

console.log(corSemaforo);
```

Comment: Esta resposta merece uma recompensa.